# Can't get my Quiz app to work

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm doing the "Learn JavaScript Properly" track on http://javascriptissexy.com/how-to-learn-javascript-properly/.

It took me forever, but I finally figured out how to get to the next question, but the choices don't change.

However, when I hard code the "questionIndex" the question and choices work fine.

Anyway here's my code (I know it's a bit messy, I'm a beginner):

http://jsfiddle.net/utfwae8d/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="quiz"></div>
    <div id="choices"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Next">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var allQuestions = [{
    question: "Who is the best in the world?",
    choices: ["CM Punk", "John Cena", "Daniel Bryan", "Roman Reigns"],
    correctAnswer: 0
},

{
    question: "Who is the current WWE World Champion?",
    choices: ["John Cena", "Brock Lesnar", "Triple H"],
    correctAnswer: 1
},

{
    question: "Where is Toronto located?",
    choices: ["Ontario", "California", "Georgia", "Texas"],
    correctAnswer: 0
},

{
    question: "What is the largest California city?",
    choices: ["Los Angeles", "San Fransico", "San Deigo", "Anahiem"],
    correctAnswer: 0
}];

var quiz = document.getElementById('quiz');
var choicesContainer = document.getElementById('choices');
var nextButton = document.querySelector('[type=button]');

var correctAnswers = 0;
var questionIndex = 0;


function showQuiz() {
    var currentQuestion = allQuestions[questionIndex].question;
    quiz.textContent = currentQuestion;

    var choicesNum = allQuestions[questionIndex].choices.length;
    var correctAnswer = allQuestions[questionIndex].correctAnswer;

    var choices;

    for (var i = 0; i < choicesNum; i++) {
        choices = allQuestions[questionIndex].choices[i];
        choicesHTML = "<input type='radio' name='choice'>" + choices + "</br>";

        choicesContainer.innerHTML += choicesHTML;
    }

    nextButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        questionIndex++;
        quiz.textContent = allQuestions[questionIndex].question;
    });


}

showQuiz();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button's click handler is not updating the answers, it's only updating the question.

I've separated the code into two functions: one that shows the quiz, and one that shows the answers.

```
var quiz = document.getElementById('quiz');
var choicesContainer = document.getElementById('choices');
var nextButton = document.querySelector('[type=button]');

var questionIndex = 0;

function showAnswers() {
    choicesContainer.innerHTML = "";
    var choicesNum = allQuestions[questionIndex].choices.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < choicesNum; i++) {
        var choice = allQuestions[questionIndex].choices[i];
        choicesHTML = "<input type='radio' name='choice'>" + choice + "</br>";
        choicesContainer.innerHTML += choicesHTML;
    }
}

function showQuiz() {
    var currentQuestion = allQuestions[questionIndex].question;
    quiz.textContent = currentQuestion;   
}

showQuiz();
showAnswers();

nextButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    questionIndex++;
    showQuiz();
    showAnswers();
});
```

Comment: Really appreciate it! I just typed out the code and it really made sense to me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the eventlistener method. I have modified your code as below and it works.

> nextButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
>       var newChoicesHTML="";
>       var newChoices;
>
> ```
> questionIndex++;
> choicesNum = allQuestions[questionIndex].choices.length;
> quiz.textContent = allQuestions[questionIndex].question;
>     for (var i = 0; i < choicesNum; i++) {
>  newChoices = allQuestions[questionIndex].choices[i];
>  newChoicesHTML+= "<input type='radio' name='choice'>" + newChoices + "</input></br>";
>
>  }
>
> choicesContainer.innerHTML = newChoicesHTML;
>
>  });
> ```

Basically the issue is on event change you are updating your question but not the answers.

Comment: Thanks so much! Works perfectly! I thought that was the problem, but felt I was repeating myself with the extra code.

Answer (score 0):

Your showQuiz function is doing 3 things:

1. setting the question text
2. setting the answer list
3. adding an event listener to the button

When the button is clicked, your code updates the question text but doesn't update the answer list. So I pulled adding the event listener out (it only needs to be executed once) and then made the button click call showQuiz again. Also I added a line to blank out the previous choices.

```
function showQuiz() {
    var currentQuestion = allQuestions[questionIndex].question;
    quiz.textContent = currentQuestion;

    var choicesNum = allQuestions[questionIndex].choices.length;
    var correctAnswer = allQuestions[questionIndex].correctAnswer;

    var choices;

    choicesContainer.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < choicesNum; i++) {
        choices = allQuestions[questionIndex].choices[i];
        choicesHTML = "<input type='radio' name='choice'>" + choices + "</br>";

        choicesContainer.innerHTML += choicesHTML;
    }
}

nextButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    questionIndex++;
    showQuiz();
});
```